# Java GC: How is "Desired Survivor Size" calculated?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am using an HotSpot JVM 1.6.0_45 on Solaris.
Here are my options concerning Heap:

```
-Xms8G
-Xmx8G
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=14
-XX:NewSize=2184M
-XX:MaxNewSize=2184M
-XX:SurvivorRatio=1
```

With that settings I expect that my Eden size and 2 Survivors will all have the same size of 728M.
Following observation into VisualVM/VisualGC, it is what we get.

Here an extract of my verbose gc logs:

```
2014-09-16T16:42:15.357+0200: 6.796: [GC 6.796: [ParNew Desired survivor size 381681664 bytes, new threshold 14 (max 14)
- age   1:   16125960 bytes,   16125960 total
- age   2:   16259512 bytes,   32385472 total
- age   3:    2435240 bytes,   34820712 total
- age   4:   17179320 bytes,   52000032 total
- age   5:   43986952 bytes,   95986984 total
- age   6:   20858328 bytes,  116845312 total
- age   7:   31571664 bytes,  148416976 total
- age   8:   41614872 bytes,  190031848 total
- age   9:   33191568 bytes,  223223416 total
- age  10:   22887432 bytes,  246110848 total
- age  11:        168 bytes,  246111016 total
- age  12:        184 bytes,  246111200 total 
: 1006811K->407353K(1490944K), 0.3248414 secs] 1006811K->407353K(7643136K), 0.3252604 secs] [Times: user=3.70 sys=0.04, real=0.33 secs] 
2014-09-16T16:42:24.650+0200: 16.089: [GC 16.089: [ParNew Desired survivor size 381681664 bytes, new threshold 14 (max 14)
- age   1:   21959968 bytes,   21959968 total
- age   2:   11169584 bytes,   33129552 total
- age   3:   15663128 bytes,   48792680 total
- age   4:    2435168 bytes,   51227848 total
- age   5:   17177584 bytes,   68405432 total
- age   6:   43976040 bytes,  112381472 total
- age   7:   20246264 bytes,  132627736 total
- age   8:   31478896 bytes,  164106632 total
- age   9:   41613872 bytes,  205720504 total
- age  10:   33190832 bytes,  238911336 total
- age  11:   22889304 bytes,  261800640 total
- age  12:        168 bytes,  261800808 total
- age  13:        184 bytes,  261800992 total
: 1152825K->302652K(1490944K), 0.3356240 secs] 1152825K->302652K(7643136K), 0.3360389 secs] [Times: user=3.96 sys=0.03, real=0.34 secs]
```

1. Why the desired survivor size is equals to "Survivor space size/2" ?

I understand the 2 survivors (728Mb each) are used alternatively by the JVM, but I am not able to understand why it seems to use half of the 728Mb (the desired survivor size defining when memory will be tenured)

2. From one GC to another, the bytes of age x+1 should be equal or less than equal to bytes of age x from previous GC. But in my example, why does age 11 of 2nd GC (22889304 bytes) is higher than age 10 of 1st GC (22887432 bytes) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for target SurvivorRation is 50%. See the jvm option  -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the first question, the desired survivor space means the max survivor space used by the live objects after each Minor GC, which is calculated by SURVIVOR_SPACE * TargetSurvivorRatio / 100, so you get half of the survivor space by default.  If the size of live object exceeds the desired survivor space, JVM will reduce the threshold to force some objects to be moved to old generation in the next GC.

I'm also interested in the 2nd question.

Comment: From guys of jclarity censum, the second question  is due to a bug in the JVM.